# How can I make elements inside the canvas responsive?

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas

I am trying to build a game using HTML5 canvas.

The canvas takes the full width and height of the browser.

```
canvas.height = innerHeight;
canvas.width = innerWidth;
```

How can I make the elements inside the canvas, like player, obstacles etc. responsive?

I know doing something like

```
addEventListener("resize", () => {
  canvas.width = innerWidth;
  canvas.height = innerHeight - 100;
});
```

will make the canvas responsive. But what about the elements drawn to the canvas?

Comment: You can't. Canvas doesn't contain any elements, it contains pixels only. The simplest solution is to draw the players etc. into their own canvases.

Comment: Maybe you're after [scaling a canvas](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-us/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/scale)?

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by responsive here? Do you mean that you want an object to be clickable, draggable etc or do you mean how to resize the whole scene if the viewport dimensions change. The latter is easy, the former needs more than just one canvas, and usually quite a bit of pixel inspection.

Comment: Take a look here: https://raw.githack.com/heldersepu/FindDuplicate/master/index.html I do not have a resize event you have to refresh the page, but the elements are "responsive" we are programmers have to keep track of each element and size it proportionally to the canvas, just go back to the basic definition of what responsive is and implement it yourself

Comment: @AHaworth By responsive I mean. Say, while positioning a player in the canvas I have used `x = canvas.width - 270`. The player's position thus looks different on different screens.

Answer (score 1):

One approach is to use two canvases:

- The onscreen canvas, which you make responsive by setting its width and height to the viewport width and height (as you do in your resize event listener)
- A second canvas element which you create using Javascript. This will have width and height dimensions that will never change (say 600px by 400px), which means you can render your game elements onto it with confidence.

Render the game on this second canvas and then, at the end of each RequestAnimationFrame cycle, copy it onto the first canvas using the ctx.drawImage() function. At this point you can do calculations to get the whole of your second canvas to fit into the first canvas leaving gaps either at the top/bottom, or on the left/right edges.

As a bonus, this will also allow your users to zoom/pan across your second canvas - if your game calls for that sort of thing.

Answer (score 0):

### Method 1

This is if you’d like the pixels to scale as well (like with pixel art)

If you want the drawings to scale as well, then change the canvas’s css height and width values, not the width and height attributes. Like this:

```
canvas.style.height = innerHeight + ‘px’;
canvas.style.width = innerWidth + ‘px’;
```

This will scale all the drawings as well.

However, using this alone, all drawings will be scaled using interpolation, giving a fuzzy look. To prevent that, add this:

```css
canvas {
  image-rendering: optimizeSpeed;
  image-rendering: -moz-crisp-edges;
  image-rendering: -webkit-optimize-contrast;
  image-rendering: -o-crisp-edges;
  image-rendering: pixelated;
  -ms-interpolation-mode: nearest-neighbor;
}
```

This will make the browser scale it using nearest-neighbor instead.

### Method 2

This method will scale all of the drawings, but will not scale pixels, and will not make it look too pixely nor fuzzy.

Like you originally did, set the width and height attributes of the canvas:

```
canvas.height = innerHeight;
canvas.width = innerWidth;
```

But create variables representing how much the canvas was scaled:

```
var scaleW = newWidth / oldWidth;
var scaleH = newHeight / oldHeight;
```

Then, add these to your drawing so you don’t have to manually scale every value:

```
ctx.save(); // saves the ctx
ctx.scale(scaleW, scaleH); // scales the drawings

// all your drawing ...

ctx.restore(); // restores the ctx, removing the scale
```

Sorry if the first didn’t work, hopefully the second should.

Comment: I did follow your answer. But the images just got fuzzy and the drawings blew up in size. Here is how the canvas looked [before](https://pasteboard.co/JMrP9Cz.png) and here is how they looked [after](https://pasteboard.co/JMrOQJo.png). What do you think might have caused this?

Comment: Ya, I updated my answer with a method that should work in that case.